# Start DrawableAnimation after finish the first one

Tags: android, animation, imageview, drawable

How can I start a drawableAnimation after the first one finish? As far as I know there is no listeners for DrawableAnimation, so I know I have to use the last frame to start the second DrawableAnimation. but I don´t get how to do it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
private ImageView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
        // Type casting the Image View
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        // Setting animation_list.xml as the background of the image view
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada01);
        // Type casting the Animation drawable
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the way to run a DrawableAnimation after finish the first one DrawableAnimation. I know how long is the animation, so I put the time to start the second one. I imagine I can calculate this time but it give trouble doing it.

```
// Start Animation
Handler nHandler = new Handler(); 
nHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {             
view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada03);
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground(); 
frameAnimation.start();
    // Start Animation 
    Handler nHandler = new Handler(); 
    nHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {             
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.entrada04);
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground(); 
    frameAnimation.start();
    }});}}, 600);
}});}}, 600);
```

This code work for me, but I found some other issue. If a press a button while runnig the first animation, the button do it´s action, but it´s interrupted by the second animation. So, i keep working to improve this code.

Thanks for your help @prakash-ubhadiya

Answer (score 0):

Try it .
It's may work for you.

```
public class AndroidAnimationActivity extends Activity {

 AnimationDrawable myAnimationDrawable;

 Timer timer;
 MyTimerTask myTimerTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView myAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myanimation);
        myAnimationDrawable 
         = (AnimationDrawable)myAnimation.getDrawable();

        myAnimation.post(
          new Runnable(){

     @Override
     public void run() {
      myAnimationDrawable.start();
     }
          });

        //Calculate the total duration
        int duration = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < myAnimationDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++){
         duration += myAnimationDrawable.getDuration(i);
        }

        timer = new Timer();
        myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(myTimerTask, duration);
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {

   timer.cancel();
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
     //Start Animation here
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
       "Animation Stopped", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }});
  }  
 }
}
```

you also apply multiple drawableAnimation using xml file

like if you have four `drawableAnimation` file **anim1.xml ,anim2.xml ,anim3.xml and anim4.xml**

then you start next animation after finish animation using xml file

NOTE : all animation **anim1.xml ,anim2.xml ,anim3.xml and anim4.xml** are  `android:oneshot="true"` **otherwise it's may not work**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@anim/anim1"
        android:duration="500"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@anim/anim2"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@anim/anim3"
        android:duration="1050"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@anim/anim4"
        android:duration="50"/>


</animation-list>
```

Comment: Thanks @prakash-ubhadiya, your code works very well, but I keep getting problems...
I mean, I got 12 animations, 3 Buttons on my layout.
Each button start an animation, Each Animation is "concatenated" like this: 
Button1 = Animation1+Animation2+Animation3+Animation4
Button2 = Animation5+Animation6+Animation7+Animation8
Button3 = Animation9+Animation10+Animation11+Animation12

So, your code use a nested class but I can´t nested again and again... or I´m doing it wrong...
What should I´ll do to get in the right way? Thanks again for your help